# Spark 2.0 - Convert DataFrame to DataSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I want to load my data and do some basic linear regression on it. So first, I need to use `VectorAssembler` to produce my features column. However, when I use `assembler.transform(df)`, `df` is a `DataFrame`, and it expects a `DataSet`. I tried `df.toDS`, but it gives `value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`. Indeed, it is a member of `org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder`.

What am I getting wrong here?

```
package main.scala

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

object Analyzer {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc   = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)    
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")  
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("data/snap/*")

    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("own", "want", "wish", "trade", "comment"))
    .setOutputCol("features")

    val df1 = assembler.transform(df)

    val formula = new RFormula().setFormula("rank ~ own + want + wish + trade + comment")
    .setFeaturesCol("features")
        .setLabelCol("rank")
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was because I still using `Spark 1.6` style of `Spark` and `SQLContext`. I changed for the `SparkSession`, and `transform()` was able to implicitly accept the `DataFrame`.

```
package main.scala

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

object Analyzer {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._

        val df = spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "false")
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")  
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .load("data/snap/*")        

        df.show()

        val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
        .setInputCols(Array("own", "want", "wish", "trade", "comment"))
        .setOutputCol("features")

        val df1 = assembler.transform(df)
   }
}
```