# Spark Scala: convert arbitrary N columns into Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I have the following data structure representing movie ids (first column) and ratings for different users for that movie in the rest of columns - something like that:

```html
+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|movieId|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|  10|  11|  12|  13|  14|  15|
+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1580|null|null| 3.5| 5.0|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|   3175|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 5.0|null|
|   3794|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 3.0|null|null|null|
|   2659|null|null|null| 3.0|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
```

I want to convert this DataFrame to a DataSet of

`final case class MovieRatings(movie_id: Long, ratings: Map[Long, Double])`

So that it would be something like

```
[1580, [1 -> null, 2 -> null, 3 -> 3.5, 4 -> 5.0, 5 -> null, 6 -> null, 7 -> null,...]]
```

Etc.

How this can be done?

The thing here is that number of users is arbitrary. And I want to zip those into a single column leaving the first column untouched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark 2.0 - Convert DataFrame to DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700213/spark-2-0-convert-dataframe-to-dataset)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because this question is How do I do it, and that question is I am trying to do this and it doesn't work, Oh wait, I need to upgrade Spark. This question is asking for a tutorial, and therefore is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to tranform your DataFrame into one with a schema matching your case class, then you can use `.as[MovieRatings]` to convert DataFrame into a `Dataset[MovieRatings]`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// define a new MapType column using `functions.map`, passing a flattened-list of
// column name (as a Long column) and column value
val mapColumn: Column = map(df.columns.tail.flatMap(name => Seq(lit(name.toLong), $"$name")): _*)

// select movie id and map column with names matching the case class, and convert to Dataset:
df.select($"movieId" as "movie_id", mapColumn as "ratings")
  .as[MovieRatings]
  .show(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the spark.sql.functions.map to create a map from arbitrary columns.  It expects a sequence alternating between keys and values which can be Column types or String's.  Here is an example:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

case class Input(movieId: Int, a: Option[Double], b: Option[Double], c: Option[Double])

val data = Input(1, None, Option(3.5), Option(1.4)) :: 
        Input(2, Option(4.2), Option(1.34), None) :: 
        Input(3, Option(1.11), None, Option(3.32)) :: Nil

val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF

// Exclude the PK column from the map
val mapKeys = df.columns.filterNot(_ == "movieId")

// Build the sequence of key, value, key, value, ..
val pairs = mapKeys.map(k => Seq(lit(k), col(k))).flatten

val mapped = df.select($"movieId", functions.map(pairs:_*) as "map")
mapped.show(false)
```

Produces this output:

```
+-------+------------------------------------+
|movieId|map                                 |
+-------+------------------------------------+
|1      |Map(a -> null, b -> 3.5, c -> 1.4)  |
|2      |Map(a -> 4.2, b -> 1.34, c -> null) |
|3      |Map(a -> 1.11, b -> null, c -> 3.32)|
+-------+------------------------------------+
```